# Word Macro: Change page orientation depending on image ratio

Tags: vba, ms-word, orientation

My macro currently does the following:

It adds a header to a Word document, then reads image files from a specific folder from the HDD and adds them to the same document with the name of the file below the image and a page break after each image. To ensure that the name doesn't get pushed to the next page (if the image fills the whole page), I set the bottom margin to a higher value before adding the image and the name and then set the margin back to the original value. This way the image is a little bit smaller and leaves enough space for the name.

What I now want to add to this:

Switch the orientation of the page depending on the images' width and height and add a manual page break, so I can have multiple orientations in the same document.

But I'm already failing at the first thing:

- How do I get the width/height/ration of the images before adding them
  to the document (`Img.Width` doesn't seem to exist in Word)? I don't care what kind of information it is, as long as it tells me if the image is landscape or portrait.
- How do I add a manual page break (`Chr(12)` just jumps to the next page without adding an actual break)?
- Adding a manual page break also means that my header text won't be used afterwards but how do I set it for the new "Section"? I'm guessing it's not still `ActiveDocument.Sections(1)` then, is it?

My code (just the image import Sub):

```
Sub ImportImages(path As String)
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim ff As Variant
    Dim Img As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fsize As Long
    Dim bottomMarginOriginal As Single
    Dim vertical As Boolean

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ff = fs.GetFolder(path).Files
    i = 0
    fsize = ff.Count
    vertical = True

    With ActiveDocument
        bottomMarginOriginal = .PageSetup.BottomMargin
        .PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal + Application.CentimetersToPoints(1) 'Add 1cm to margin

        For Each Img In ff
            Select Case Right(Img.name, 4)
                Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png", "tiff", ".tif"
                    If i <> 0 Then
                        .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(12) 'Add page break before adding the img
                        Debug.Print "Width: " & Img.Width 'Error message: Doesn't exist!
                    Else
                        .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "test text"
                        .PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape 'TODO: Check the img ratio
                        vertical = False
                    End If

                    i = i + 1
                    .Characters.Last.InlineShapes.AddPicture filename:=Img 'Add the img
                    .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & Img.name 'Add a line break and the img name
            End Select
        Next
    End With
        ActiveDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

This code does add section breaks but it seems like it sets the orientation for the whole document, not just the current section, so I end up with the same orientation on all pages, plus the images are only added in the very last section without any page/section breaks in between. How do I fix this?

```
Sub ImportImages(path As String)
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim ff As Variant
    Dim img As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fsize As Long
    Dim bottomMarginOriginal As Single
    Dim topMarginOriginal As Single
    Dim vertical As Boolean

    Dim objShell As New Shell
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As ShellFolderItem

    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ff = fs.GetFolder(path).Files
    i = 0
    fsize = ff.Count
    vertical = True
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(path)

    With ActiveDocument
        bottomMarginOriginal = .PageSetup.BottomMargin
        topMarginOriginal = .PageSetup.TopMargin

        For Each img In ff
            Select Case Right(img.name, 4)
                Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png", "tiff", ".tif"
                    Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(img.name)
                    width = objFile.ExtendedProperty("{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 3")
                    height = objFile.ExtendedProperty("{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 4")

                    If width > height Then
                        If vertical = False Then 'Already landscape -> just add page break
                            .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(12)
                        Else 'Set to landscape
                            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
                            .PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
                            .PageSetup.TopMargin = topMarginOriginal 'Adjust margins to new orientation
                            .PageSetup.RightMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .PageSetup.LeftMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "test " & i 'Set header
                            vertical = False
                        End If
                    ElseIf height > width Then
                        If vertical = True Then 'Already portrait -> just add page break on page 2+
                            If i <> 0 Then
                                .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(12)
                            End If
                        Else 'Set to portrait
                            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
                            .PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
                            .PageSetup.TopMargin = topMarginOriginal 'Adjust margins to new orientation
                            .PageSetup.RightMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .PageSetup.LeftMargin = bottomMarginOriginal
                            .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "test " & i 'Set header
                            vertical = True
                        End If
                    Else
                        If i <> 0 Then
                            .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(12) 
                        End If
                    End If

                    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal + Application.CentimetersToPoints(1) 'Add 1cm to the bottom margin
                    i = i + 1
                    .Characters.Last.InlineShapes.AddPicture filename:=img
                    .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & img.name
                    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = bottomMarginOriginal 'Reset bottom margin to default
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Img` is a [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object), no reason for it to have a Width property. However, [ShellForlderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty) may have an extended property "Dimensions", you can try to look into it.

Comment: @VincentG Oh, sorry, I'm still pretty new to VBA. I tried it like [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26934989/Can-I-retrieve-a-graphic-file's-image-resolution-as-an-extended-property.html) but the the first line (`Dim objShell As New Shell`) already throws an `user-defined type not defined` error. Is the Shell part of VBA for Word? I know that some VBA classes are only available for Access but don't work with Word.

Comment: If you want to use early binding, you need to add a reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" in the vba editor.

Comment: @VincentG Ah, thanks. It's working now but it returns something like "?1024 x 682?" (same problem as in the link: there's no info for "Resolution", "Vertical Resolution" and "Horizontal Resolution"), which I'd have to parse for every image. Is there maybe a faster way of getting the size? I edited it in my question: I don't care what I get exactly (width/height, ratio, orientation...), as long as it tells me in some way if the image is landscape or portrait.

Comment: Did you try SCIDs?  Like "{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 3" for Horizontal size or "{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 5" for horizontal resolution?

Comment: `objFile.ExtendedProperty("{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 3")` works, thanks! The second one is `{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 4` (5 and 6 are for dpi). Going to use that then unless someone knows how to get the data out of the File object (so without opening a new Shell). Do you also happen to know how to add the page break and how to handle the header for every section afterwards?

Comment: @VincentG I managed to get the section break to work (`Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage`) and while it does also change the orientation of the page, it seems to set it for the whole document, not just the section. I end up with a couple of empty pages and all the images are added after the last section break instead of inbetween breaks. I'm going to add the new code in my question. Do you know what's wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the image dimensions beforehand. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub AddPics()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, StrTxt As String, Rng As Range, vCol
Dim sAspect As Single, sLndWdth As Single, sLndHght As Single
Dim sMgnL As Single, sMgnR As Single, sMgnT As Single, sMgnB As Single, sMgnG As Single
'Select and insert the Pics
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select image files and click OK"
  .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png"
  .FilterIndex = 2
  If .Show = -1 Then
    Set vCol = .SelectedItems
  Else
    Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With ActiveDocument
  'Create a paragraph Style with 0 space before/after & centre-aligned
  On Error Resume Next
  .Styles.Add Name:="Pic", Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
  With .Styles("Pic").ParagraphFormat
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceBefore = 0
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0
  With .PageSetup
    sMgnL = .LeftMargin: sMgnR = .RightMargin: sMgnT = .TopMargin: sMgnB = .BottomMargin: sMgnG = .Gutter
  End With
  Set Rng = Selection.Range
  With Rng
    .Paragraphs.Last.Style = "Pic"
    For i = 1 To vCol.Count
      .InsertAfter vbCr
      .Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
      .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=vCol(i), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Characters.Last
      'Get the Image name for the Caption
      StrTxt = Split(Split(vCol(i), "\")(UBound(Split(vCol(i), "\"))), ".")(0)
      'Insert the Caption below the picture
      .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & StrTxt
    Next
    .Characters.First.Text = vbNullString
    .Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
      With .InlineShapes(i)
        'Reorient pages for landscape pics
        If .Height / .Width < 1 Then
          With .Range.Sections(1).PageSetup
            .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
            .LeftMargin = sMgnL: .RightMargin = sMgnR: .TopMargin = sMgnT: .BottomMargin = sMgnB: .Gutter = sMgnG
            sLndWdth = .PageWidth - sMgnL - sMgnR - sMgnG
            sLndHght = .PageHeight - sMgnT - sMgnB
          End With
          .LockAspectRatio = True
          .ScaleHeight = 100
          If .Height > sLndHght Then .Height = sLndHght
          If .Width > sLndWdth Then .Width = sLndWdth
        End If
      End With
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I open a FileDialog earlier to pick the folder, then pass the path to my "ImportImages" sub. ;) I understand what you're doing (I think), so thanks for the code! But, to be honest, I'd rather check the ratio right before I add an image because won't going through everything again afterwards to also resize the images (if I orient the page, then add the image, Word resizes it properly on its own) take longer, which would be especially noticeable if there are 20+ images (which is highly likely)?

Comment: @Neph I suggest you try it. The difference in time is hardly likely to be significant, especially as my code doesn't have to go through the process of working out the orientation for every page. I ran a test on my laptop with 50 jpg images - most being full-page landscape format - in just 20 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't need a shell for checking, that's true (not sure how that affects it performance-wise) but resizing the images probably balances it out again. Can I give your `vCol` the list I get from `fs.GetFolder(path).Files` (I want to use a folder because I have to read it for something else anyway)? How does your code ensure that the img name isn't pushed to the next page with tall images? I'm going to try it but I also want to find out why my edited code doesn't work as expected and how I can fix it. If I just copy yours, I'm not going to learn anything from it.